# HTML mustache templates - how to get first item of collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, mustache

I'm using mustache templates to correctly generate bootstrap accordions. Now I need to pass a prefix to the top item id = 'accorElM' and thought I could do something like this.

```
 <div class="accordion" id='{{#DataResult[0].prefixID}}_accorElM'>
```

IE, get the first item in the collection

Is this possible to do?

Code sample:

```
  <div class="accordion" id='accorElM'>

              {{#DataResult}}

                     <div class="accordion-group">
                                <div class="accordion-heading">
                                    <a style="text-align: left; text-decoration: none" class="accordion-toggle btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent='#{{prefixID}}accorEl' href='#{{prefixID}}collapseEl_{{id}}'>
                                        <i class="icon-globe"></i>&nbsp;{{tipo}}<i class="icon-chevron-down pull-right"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div id='collapseEl_{{id}}' class="accordion-body collapse">
                                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                                        <div class="row-fluid">
                                            <div class="span9">

                                                <address>

                                                    <br />
                                                   {{zona}}
                                                    <br />
                                                    {{cpostal}}
                                                    <br />
                                                    {{pais}}
                                                </address>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="span3">
                                                <div class="pull-right">

                                                  .....

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

            {{/DataResult}}

          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your data must be something like this:

```
{"DataResult":[
    {"prefixID":"1","name":"first"},
    {"prefixID":"2","name":"second"}
    ]
}
```

but in the mustache template file, I don't think you can index the object items. The approach that I would have taken would involve manipulating the Json object in javascript(or even in the backend when constructing the object) before rendering it.
 In your case, if you need the prefixID of the first item in the DataResult. you could alter the object to make it look like this:

```
{"DataResult":[
    {"prefixID":"1","name":"first"},
    {"prefixID":"2","name":"second"}
    ],
 "theIdIWant":"1"
}
```

and then in the template file:

```
<div class="accordion" id='{{theIdIWant}}_accorElM'>

          {{#DataResult}}
                 <div class="accordion-group">
                 ///////
                 </div>
          {{/DataResult}}
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sometimes we make things complicated when it is not needed.
  Your answer makes perfect sense! Thank you for opening my eyes :)